# Increase width of a div if font size increase using CSS

Tags: html, css

How to increase the width of a div if font size increase using CSS?

I have the below code.

```css
.wpwi_main {
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
.wpwi_top {
    text-align: center;
}

.wpwi_outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.wpwi_row {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
}

.wpwi_row>div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 13%;
    padding-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpwi_main">
    <div class="wpwi_top">Top</div>
    <div class="wpwi_outer">
        <div>Outer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_inner">
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Time</div>
            <div>8:02 PM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Date</div>
            <div>13 Aug 2022</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Pressure</div>
            <div>999 hPa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Visibility</div>
            <div>10000 Meter</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Cloudiness</div>
            <div>98%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunrise</div>
            <div>5:37 AM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunset</div>
            <div>6:39 PM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code if I use `font-size: 9px;` in `.wpwi_main` I get this output [image]

and If I use `font-size: 20px;` in `.wpwi_main` I get this output [image].

How can I increase width of `.wpwi_row>div:nth-child(1)` div if font size increase ?

Comment: Try changing `width: 13%` to `min-width: 13%` or to `width: fit-content`

Comment: You appear to be making this harder than it needs to be; why not just align the text so that it's centered without using all the magic numbers: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oday4cu2/)? Then the text can grow and everything is - or seems to be - okay automatically.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas. Your solution is close to my requirements. I need fist column text left aligned and close to second column. Could you please do that ?

Comment: @abu: that may be difficult (but probably do-able), may I ask why you need the text left-aligned (not to justify the requirement, but because the requirement might inform the solution or prevent certain alternatives being used)?

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas. I would like to display data in this way. I have to increase and decrease font size. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `em`s as your unit to set your width instead of `%`.  `em` is relative to the font-size of the parent so if the font size changes, the width will change to match.

Although if you don't have enough space to start with, then your text is always going to overlap anyway due to the nature of flex

```css
.wpwi_row {
  display: flex;
}

.wpwi_row div:first-child {
  width: 4em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.large {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpwi_row">
  <div>Pressure</div>
  <div>999 hPa</div>
</div>
<div class="wpwi_row large">
  <div>Pressure</div>
  <div>999 hPa</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wpwi_main {
    border: 1px solid aliceblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.wpwi_top {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  
}

.wpwi_outer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
   
}

.wpwi_row {
    display: flex;
    width:100%;
}

.wpwi_row>div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpwi_main">
    <div>
    <div class="wpwi_top">Top</div>
    <div class="wpwi_outer">Outer</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_inner">
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Time</div>
            <div>8:02 PM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Date</div>
            <div>13 Aug 2022</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Pressure</div>
            <div>999 hPa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Visibility</div>
            <div>10000 Meter</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Cloudiness</div>
            <div>98%</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunrise</div>
            <div>5:37 AM</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wpwi_row">
            <div>Sunset</div>
            <div>6:39 PM</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should just increase and adjust the width percentage from 13% to 30%    .wpwi_row>div:nth-child(1) {
    width: 30%;
    padding-left: 40%;
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// caching a reference to the document, because I don't enjoy typing all that much:
const D = document,
  // various helper functions because (again) I like to minimise typing;
  // this function allows the creation of new elements, and assigns various
  // properties if passed in a second ('props') Object:
    create = (tag,props) => Object.assign(D.createElement(tag), props),
  // get(), an alias for document, or element, querySelector(), which
  // takes a selector and passes it to the querySelector() method,
  // and sets the context argument by default to 'document', or if
  // provided by the user, takes the context of an Element:
  get = (sel, context = D) => context.querySelector(sel),
  // as above, but with querySelectorAll() and converting the iterable
  // NodeList into an Array:
  getAll = (sel, context = D) => [...context.querySelectorAll(sel)],
  // caching the <input> element:
  input = get('input');

// binding the anonymous arrow function of EventTarget.addEventListener()
// as the event-handler for the 'input' event on the <input>:
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  // caching the <input> within the function (not entirely necessary in
  // this case, but it's a personal preference to cache references within
  // a function where possible/sensible to do so):
  let target = e.currentTarget,
    // caching the value of the <input>, and parsing it to a number in
    // base-10:
    value = parseInt(target.value, 10);
  // assigning the value of the <input> as the value of the --fs custom-
  // property on the .wpwi_main element:
  get('.wpwi_main').style.setProperty('--fs', `${value}px`);
  // assigning the value as the text-content of the <output> element:
  get('output').textContent = `${value}px`;
});

// when the DOMContentLoaded event fires, the anonymous Arrow function
// is fired:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  // here we trigger the 'input' event on the <input> element in
  // order to assign the value of the <input> to the --fs property
  // to correctly assign the font-size on page-load:
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
});
```

```css
/* a simple reset to remove default margins and padding, and
   to force the browser to use the same algorithm to calculate
   element sizes, including the border-width and padding in
   the assigned width: */
*,::before,::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-block: 1em
  margin-inline: auto;
  inline-size: 80vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.wpwi_main {
  border: 1px solid aliceblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* assigning the custom property --fs as the font-size
     of the element, and its descendants: */
  font-size: var(--fs);
}

.wpwi_top {
  text-align: center;
}

/* this is effectively as I found it, though I've changed the
   CSS to use logical properties: */
.wpwi_outer {
  text-align: center;
  /* in left-to-right languages (such as English) this is
     equivalent to margin-left and margin-right specified
     in one shorthand (see the references for a link to an
     article/documentation): */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* in languages such as English (left-to-right, top-to-bottom)
     this is equivalent to padding-bottom: */
  padding-block-end: 20px;
  /* again, in English, this is equivalent to 'width': */
  inline-size: 100%;
}

.wpwi_row {
  /* purely for visibility of the wrapping element's dimensions: */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ccc2 0 3px, transparent 3px 9px);
  display: flex;
  /* spacing adjacent elements by 1em: */
  gap: 1em;
  /* laying out elements to incorporate space between them: */
  justify-content: space-between;
  inline-size: 100%;
}

.wpwi_row > div {
  /* basing the size of the elements on a 50% original size: */
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.wpwi_row > div:first-child {
  /* using a text-indent to have the text left-aligned (or start-aligned)
     but moved away from the inline-start edge (left, in English) by the
     result of the calculation, using the calc() function; here I subtract
     the width of 10ch units (approximately a ten-character width, approximately
     based on the 'width' of the 0 (zero) character in the current font of
     the element): */
  text-indent: calc(100% - 10ch);
}

.wpwi_row > div:first-child::after {
  /* showing a colon (':') character after the first-child
     of the .wpwi_row element: */
  content: ':';
}
```

```html
<!-- a means by which the font-size can be dynamically adjusted to demonstrate
     the functionality of the CSS: -->
<label>Change font-size
<input type="range" min=9 max=50 value=9>
<output></output>
</label>
<div class="wpwi_main">
  <div class="wpwi_top">Top</div>
  <div class="wpwi_outer">
    <div>Outer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wpwi_inner">
    <div class="wpwi_row">
      <div>Time</div>
      <div>8:02 PM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_row">
      <div>Date</div>
      <div>13 Aug 2022</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_row">
      <div>Pressure</div>
      <div>999 hPa</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_row">
      <div>Visibility</div>
      <div>10000 Meter</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_row">
      <div>Cloudiness</div>
      <div>98%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_row">
      <div>Sunrise</div>
      <div>5:37 AM</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpwi_row">
      <div>Sunset</div>
      <div>6:39 PM</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cvatdue3/1/).

References:

- CSS

  - [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).
  - [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
  - [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).
  - [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
  - [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
  - [`ch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#ch).
  - [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
  - [CSS Custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [CSS Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
  - [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
  - [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inline-size).
  - [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
  - [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
  - [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
  - [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
  - [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
  - [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
  - [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
  - [`padding-block-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block-end).
  - [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient).
  - [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
  - [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`Element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
  - [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).